# How to set the length of a line using openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, distance, line

I'm trying edit a polygon by changing the length of some lines by code. Found [this method](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Util-js.html#Util.destinationVincenty) to calculate based on the bearing.

But I didn't find anything on how to calculate the bearing, before I start research my math notes and code this bearing calculation, any recomendations ?

thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish and how the link applies to what you are doing?  I'm not clear on whether you are creating new polygons or editing existing ones.

Comment: editing existing ones.